# PHP if database has url echo URL using hyperlinked button

Tags: php

I am trying to see if a file in my database exists, and if it does, show that file as a hyperlinked button. The file is a URL. I am able to get the file to show accordingly, but the button shows even if there is no hyperlink. I have been researching everywhere to find out how I can echo the button only if there is a corresponding file but have had no luck. Just can get it right. Here is what I have and appreciate the help.

```
<?php if (file_exists($video))?><a class="videobutton" href="<?php echo $video; ?>"></a>
```

Comment: there isn't enough information to support the question, seeing it's database-related. The question is unclear.

Comment: file exists in database ??? are you sure  or you are getting the link of the file from database and then check if it exists in a folder ?

Comment: The file (link) exists in the database. I'm able to grab it and show it through the button. But the button itself shows even if there is no link. I don't want the button to show if there is no link to go with it.

Comment: @user8400881 Accept the question please if solved your problem so it will be closed

Answer (score 1):

So based on Your Comment that you want to hide the whole button if the file is not found so this is how to do it :

```
<?php

if (file_exists($video)): ?>

<a class="videobutton" href="<?php echo $video; ?>"></a>

<?php endif; ?>
```

OR

```
 if (file_exists($video)){ ?>

<a class="videobutton" href="<?php echo $video; ?>"></a>

<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php if (file_exists($video)){?>
<a class="videobutton" href="<?php echo $video; ?>"></a>
<?php } 
else {
///
} ?>
```

In my opinion you missed the "{" brackets within the if statement.

Comment: I'm not sure what to add for the else--I don't want to show anything at all if there is no link in the database.

Comment: Then just leave the else block out? You don't need to specify it.

Comment: if I leave else out, the button shows even when there is nothing attached to it.

Comment: When you write it like this it doesn't work? o.O <?php if (file_exists($video)){?>
<a class="videobutton" href="<?php echo $video; ?>"></a>
<?php } ?>

Comment: When I write it like that, the button disappears entirely ;/

Comment: This worked! Thanks for helping out! <?php if ($video){?><a class="videobutton" href="<?php echo $video; ?>"></a><?php } ?>